# Pyserial и Arduino. python скриптом не пишет в порт

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, arduino, serial

Дано:

- Win7 x64,
- Python 3.6/3.5/2.7 ; Pyserial 3.3,
- IDE Arduino,
- Плата Arduino mega на Atmega 2560.

Ардуино выполняет свою задачу при открытии порта через `idi arduino` или через консоль питон идеально. Но при запуске скрипта:

1. Ардуино не видит данные в порту.
2. Ардуино не выполняет код.

Что делает Arduino: проверяет наличие данных в порту, если есть — спамит `1` и зажигает светодиод.

Код(пишу в ручную с телефона, мелкие опечатки быть могут):

```
Void setup()
{

}

Void loop()
{

    If (Serial.available()>0)
    {
          Serial.println(1);
          digitalWrite(4,1);
    }
}
```

Код Python:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=2)
print(ser.in_Waiting())   // выводит 0
ser.write(b'1')    
print(ser.readline())       //выводит b''
print(ser.in_waiting())    //выводит 0
```

---

С настройками порта играл: `rsf` и `str` (скорее всего неправильно написал, но, надеюсь, понятно) чередовал, даже одновременно вкл, так же играл с `write_timeout`.

Думаю поставить линукс на ноут и параметр эксклюзив False дать (на вин низя, матерится на папку `win32` в папке `serial`, поставляемое `сpyserial.64` не нашел), и рассмотреть все это более внимательно, но, мб.

Кто-нибудь знает, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить задержку на 2-3 секунды, после создания серийного порта и только потом пишите/читайте данные из порта.

Comment: Да! Помогло! Спасибо большое! Правда, не совсем понятно, почему это сработало, ведь питон и так ждет 2 сек во время чтения... надо курить мануалы) п.с. не вижу галочки у этого коммента:с только у предыдущего. Телефонная версия немного запутанная)

Comment: Это связано с тем, что ардуино при включении ждет какое-то время команду на загрузку прошивки, поэтому в это время пытаться с ней взаимодейстовать не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно корректно настроить последовательный порт.

Вот настройки (на языке Си):

```
// 8N1
toptions.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
toptions.c_cflag |= CS8;
// no flow control
toptions.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
toptions.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;  // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines
toptions.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // turn off s/w flow ctrl
toptions.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // make raw
toptions.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; // make raw 
// see: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html
toptions.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
toptions.c_cc[VTIME] = 20;
```

Полный код клиента Arduino на Cи [здесь](https://sites.google.com/site/vanyambauseslinux/arduino/host-klient-arduino-na-s-linux).