# Arduino не читает отправленный через порт текст, но видит \n

Tags: c++, linux, c, arduino

Т.Е. при использовании кода под Linux строка с ардуино получается вроде правильно, а вот передача как-то неправильно работает.
Arduino подключается через USB, и в ОС виден как usbtty.
При попытке отправить строку, он должен отправить её обратно, если получает \n, но он ничего не отправляет обратно, хотя \n правильно считывается, и ардуино пытается отправить принятое обратно. При попытке просто отправить любую строку при получении \n то всё работает правильно. Кроме того, при попытке отправить одну и ту же строку периодически количество принятых байт меняется, хотя текст не менялся.
Из Arduino IDE всё нормально работает.
P.S. простите за возможные глупые ошибки, нас с паскаля сразу на ассемблер кинули без C++, пришлось самоучиваться :)
Код ардуино:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

String inString = "";

void loop() 
{
  while (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    int inChar = Serial.read();
    if (inChar == '\n') 
    {
      Serial.println(inString);
      inString = "";
    }
    else inString += (char)inChar;
  }
}
```

Код  C++ для Linux:

```
    // C library headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

// Linux headers
#include <fcntl.h> // Contains file controls like O_RDWR
#include <errno.h> // Error integer and strerror() function
#include <termios.h> // Contains POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <unistd.h> // write(), read(), close()
int main()
{
    // Open the serial port. Change device path as needed (currently set to an standard FTDI USB-UART cable type device)
    int serial_port = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);

    // Create new termios struc, we call it 'tty' for convention
    struct termios tty;
    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

    // Read in existing settings, and handle any error
    if(tcgetattr(serial_port, &tty) != 0) 
    {
        printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }


/// /// /// /// /// ///


    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // Clear parity bit, disabling parity (most common)
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // Clear stop field, only one stop bit used in communication (most common)
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8; // 8 bits per byte (most common)
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; // Disable RTS/CTS hardware flow control (most common)
    tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; // Turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines (CLOCAL = 1)

    tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; // Disable echo
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHOE; // Disable erasure
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHONL; // Disable new-line echo
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ISIG; // Disable interpretation of INTR, QUIT and SUSP
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // Turn off s/w flow ctrl
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL); // Disable any special handling of received bytes

    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; // Prevent special interpretation of output bytes (e.g. newline chars)
    tty.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR; // Prevent conversion of newline to carriage return/line feed
    // tty.c_oflag &= ~OXTABS; // Prevent conversion of tabs to spaces (NOT PRESENT ON LINUX)
    // tty.c_oflag &= ~ONOEOT; // Prevent removal of C-d chars (0x004) in output (NOT PRESENT ON LINUX)

    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;    // Wait for up to 1s (10 deciseconds), returning as soon as any data is received.
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;


/// /// /// /// /// ///


    // Set in/out baud rate to be 9600
    cfsetispeed(&tty, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&tty, B9600);

    // Save tty settings, also checking for error
    if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) 
    {
        printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    L1:

    // Allocate memory for read buffer, set size according to your needs
    char read_buf [256];
    memset(&read_buf, '\0', sizeof(read_buf));

    // Read bytes. The behaviour of read() (e.g. does it block?,
    // how long does it block for?) depends on the configuration
    // settings above, specifically VMIN and VTIME
    int num_bytes = read(serial_port, &read_buf, sizeof(read_buf));

    // n is the number of bytes read. n may be 0 if no bytes were received, and can also be -1 to signal an error.
    if (num_bytes < 0) 
    {
        printf("Error reading: %s", strerror(errno));
    }

    // Here we assume we received ASCII data, but you might be sending raw bytes (in that case, don't try and
    // print it to the screen like this!)
    printf("Read %i bytes. Received message: %s", num_bytes, read_buf);

    tcflush(serial_port, TCIFLUSH);

    printf("Enter command: ");
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    str += "\n";
    const char * msg;
    msg = str.c_str();
    //msg += '\n';

    // Write to serial port
    //unsigned char msg[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'p', '\n'};
    write(serial_port, msg, sizeof(msg));

    goto L1;
    if (getchar()  == '\n')
    {
        close(serial_port);
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        goto L1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Попробуйте создать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), это существенно упростит работу для помощи вам. В вашем примере очень много кода. На вашем месте я бы во-первых выкинул максимум кода так, чтобы проблема осталась, и во-вторых очень подробно описал бы проблему, что сделали, что ожидалось, что получилось. Если вы всё это сделаете, скорее всего вам очень быстро помогут. А так вот даже мне сейчас нужно очень много времени, чтобы разобраться в вашем коде (при том, что даже не очень ясно, в чём именно проблема)

Comment: код в ардуино урезал, для linux не урезал, так как особо не разобрался в нём, и проблема имено там. Спасибо за критику.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наверное всё-таки не так

```
write(serial_port, msg, sizeof(msg));
```

а вот так

```
write(serial_port, msg, strlen(msg));
```

Comment: Спасибо за указание на мою криворукость! Я думал, что мой код не правильный,  уже взял пример с интернета, а проблема была всё время в моём sizeof! Большое спасибо! :)

Answer (score 2):

1. для начала попробуйте уменьшить скорость до 9600-38400. это железо, на кабель между устройствами могут быть наводки, напр., wifi.
2. приём на линуксе с консоли можно организовать через `cat </dev/ttyUSB0` и менять параметры данного терминала через stty
3. после получения устойчивого обмена, просмотрите полученные параметры stty и скопируйте в ваш c-код.
4. пересмотрите готовые примеры arduino-проектов.
5. могу ошибаться, если вы не применяете RTS/CTS (соответствующие контакты на разьёмах, 5 проводов в кабеле), то следует использовать XON/XOFF, где используются только 3 провода.

Comment: про паузу посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658231/pyserial-%d0%b8-arduino-python-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82?rq=1

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, обязательно попробую.